# Limit the number of items in a mod_articles_category module?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, module-display, mod-articles-category

I have a really simple question: is it possible to limit the number of items displayed when using the `mod_articles_category` module? If not, it's possible to add a paginator?

Because I have a category of news that it's growing fast, and the `mod_articles_category` displays all the articles from the given category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In module parameters, tab Filtering Options, field Count determines number of articles shown, 0 for All